# $(window).scroll(function () does not work in chrome and firefox anymore

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, scroll

I got a strange problem. Yesterday everything seems find. Today when I start to work on my script the `$(window).scroll(function ()` dosent work anymore.

I havent changed any code.

I testet and testet, and figured out that this was not working in Chrome and Firefox anymore. Only thing I did was update Firefox to 11.0 version. But I use Chrome for my personal use.

Here is the code that is not working anymore:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

      alert("WORKING!);
}
});
```

I only get the alert message in Internet Explorer. The problem seems to be around this line here:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
```

I have also tried  and  just before the last  on the current page.

Any ideas how to fix this? I need this infinity scroll function to work in all browsers.

Regards

Comment: You have a syntax error. `alert("WORKING!);` should be `alert("WORKING!");`

Comment: I see that, but this was code example I was writing here. This is what I have in the original code a lert (" dd " )

Comment: `scroll()` is working for me in Chrome on the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) for it. Are you sure it's `scroll()` that's not working, and not something with comparison?

Comment: I've tried your sample (minus the syntax error) in Chrome 17, FF 10 and FF 11. In all three, when reaching the bottom of the page after scrolling, the messagebox appears. I don't know if that is what's meant to happen.

Comment: Its the comparison I guess. It cant figure out document heigh is my guess

Comment: @Kenny Flashlight: In the original code you have "a lert" ? :)

Comment: I use alert() but I get cencored when I wrote In here.  I tried to change things here to get document.height right in cross-browsers.                       $.getDocHeight = function(){
     var D = document;
     return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight,    D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
};

alert( $.getDocHeight() );

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: jprofitt: Im making a infinity scroll function. Scroll down the page, get more data from DB and show them on screen

Comment: beside the missing ", this works on FF 10.0.2 and 11: http://jsfiddle.net/CXhSy/1/. There has to be a problem somewhere else, do you want to show us more of your code / example site?

Answer (score 0):

its working for me in FF 10.2.0 and now i updated too to FF 11.0 and its still working. Also in Chrome 17.0.963.79:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tmvq/

code:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    alert('WORKING!');
}

alert($(window).scrollTop()); // no scroll ... so: 0
alert($(document).height()); // like: 477
alert($(window).height());​ // like: 477
```

**Also be sure you have a valid DOCTYPE!**

Comment: Well, so any good answers on why this is not working for me anymore?

Comment: is your HTML code valid and no quirks mode? does the fiddle work for you? or just the code on your webpage?

Comment: the fiddle works yes. And I checked with my HTML code. I just deletet everything in my index.php file, and pasted in the code from fiddle and guess what!  Nothing happend. Couldnt get any alerts either.

Comment: you get no alerts becouse you have an error if you delete everything becouse jquery isnt loaded????
i bet your HTML istn valid as its no browser issue if the fiddle works.

Comment: What I just did is this. I have a blank .php page. Nothing in it. Pasted in the cod jquery code. IF I write a alert("test") I get this alert poping up. IF I paste in the code from fiddle, no alerts. Nothing. Just tried in every browser, and noen seems to work anymore. Im running windows  8 beta, maybe that is a problem. I will now format my computer and re-install windows and see if that helps me out

Comment: if you paste the fiddle code in a blank .php it WILL NOT WORK IN ANY BROWSER becouse there are jquery function in it and you need jquery loaded!!!!!!!

Comment: jquery.js I have loaded in top of that file

Comment: run your output in the w3c validator... and tell us if you have valid DTD

Comment: don't forget to wrap the JS from the fiddle inside `$(function(){ /*CODE HERE */ });

Comment: No DOCTYPE found, and unknown root element. Aborting validation.
 Unable to Determine Parse Mode!

Comment: and you answered your question yourself! insert a valid doctype and it will work 100% !

Comment: Everything sorted out in this end, but $(window).scroll(function() does not work, even after I use a blank .php doc and load jquery. Its not working in jfidle either. Test here.   http://jsfiddle.net/8tmvq/2/

Comment: how should your fiddle work if you put alert in a .scroll() callback function if there no scrollbar to scroll with to even trigger the callback??? :P